# fine-uploader trouble with formatting the code, events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I need to have multiple events associated with the fineuploader instantiation, but I'm not sure how to go about it.  Can't they be added within the fineuploader properties, etc.?  Isn't the complete event then called onComplete? Is there an example that exists?  Also, I'm confused about the number of closing brackets, etc.  When I originally cut and pasted this code in, there was an extra )}; that sat outside.  I removed that, but I'm not sure if that's cool or not for the actual code.  Any help is appreciated, as I've been toying with this for hours.  Some variables have been set outside this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var controlType = '@Model.ControlType';
    var surveyItemResultId = @Model.Results[0].SurveyItemResultId;
    var itemId = @Model.SurveyItemId;
    var instance = @Model.Results[0].SurveyInstanceID;
    var loopingCounter = 0; 

    var fineuploader = $('#files-upload').fineUploader({            
        request:
        {
            endpoint: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Survey")',
            customHeaders: { Accept: 'application/json' },
            params: {
                surveyInstanceId: (function () { return instance; }),
                surveyItemResultId: (function () { return surveyItemResultId; }),
                itemId: (function () { return itemId; }),
                loopingIndex: (function () { return loopingCounter++; })
            }             
        },
        validation: {
                acceptFiles: ['image/*','application/pdf','text/csv'] , 
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'csv', 'pdf'],
                sizeLimit: 1024*1024*1 // 1MB
            },
       multiple: true,
       text: {
                uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>Select your upload file(s)'
            }           
    })                   

      .on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            alert("Success: " + responseJSON.success);

            uploadedFileCounter++;
            if (filesToUpload == uploadedFileCounter)
            {
                alert("DONE UPLOADING!");
            }           

    }).on('submitted', function(event, id, filename) {
            filesToUpload++;
            alert("submitted: " + filesToUpload);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The extra `})` was probably to close your `$(document).ready` inner function. Looks like you're defining your events right. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: You're right, the extra }); is for the doc ready.

I've never needed to chain events and I can only get my code to work when I remove the .on('submitted'), and a });.

The .on('complete') logic fires as expected.

Comment: Got it, it was subtle, but I had the incorrect syntax.  Top code has been updated.

Comment: I've rolled back your change.  Please do not edit your question in this way.  It will be confusing to others in the future when reading this question.  In the future, add an answer if you have a fix for your problem.  I am currently typing up my own answer with some fixes and suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is littered with syntax and other errors.  First off, you are referencing `filesToUpload` and `uploadedFileCounter` variables that are not defined anywhere in your code.  Second, you have an extra closing bracket in your code.

There are also some formating issues with your code.  First, Your code is inconsistently indented.  Second, you are mixing placement of curly brackets.

Here is your original code with my adjustments:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var controlType = '@Model.ControlType',
        surveyItemResultId = @Model.Results[0].SurveyItemResultId,
        itemId = @Model.SurveyItemId,
        instance = @Model.Results[0].SurveyInstanceID,
        loopingCounter = 0,
        filesToUpload = 0,
        uploadedFileCounter = 0;


    var fineuploader = $('#files-upload').fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Survey")',
            customHeaders: { Accept: 'application/json' },
            params: {
                surveyInstanceId: (function () { return instance; }),
                surveyItemResultId: (function () { return surveyItemResultId; }),
                itemId: (function () { return itemId; }),
                loopingIndex: (function () { return loopingCounter++; })
            }
        },
        validation: {
            acceptFiles: ['image/*','application/pdf','text/csv'] ,
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'csv', 'pdf'],
            sizeLimit: 1024*1024*1 // 1MB
        },
        multiple: true,
        text: {
            uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>Select your upload file(s)'
        }
    })

        .on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            alert("Success: " + responseJSON.success);

            uploadedFileCounter++;
            if (filesToUpload == uploadedFileCounter) {
                alert("DONE UPLOADING!");
            }

        }).on('submitted', function(event, id, filename) {
            filesToUpload++;
            alert("submitted: " + filesToUpload);
        });
});
```

Comment: Sorry about the editing of the original, wasn't sure how that part works.  Yeah, I found the extra curly bracket too through trial and lots of error.  At the very bottom of the original question I did mention that some variables were set outside the displayed code, and the two you're mentioning are these.  Thanks for the editing of the formatting, as I have no real clue how that should go, especially during the events.

Thanks for your help, as usual.

Comment: No problem.  In the future, I suggest using a good IDE that will reveal these types of issues during development.  I personally use (and love) IntelliJ IDEA by JetBrains.